# Split sheet into multiple sheets based on multiple column values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, split, divide

I have a piece of testing equipment (brake dynamometer) that generates *a lot* of data and I would like to automate the analysis process a bit.

I would like to have a Google Sheets template that I can copy/paste raw data into, and have that data automatically filtered into different tabs.  I would like it divided based on columns A (Cycle) and then subdivided by column B (Test).  Each test will have a unique tab, 1:1, 1:2, 1:3,...1:20...20:1...20:20, etc...
I anticipate 10k-40k rows of data, 1-20 Cycles and 1-20 Tests within each Cycle, each Test is about 250 rows of data so that could be 100k rows to filter (bonus points will be awarded to anyone who can make it run 'fast').

Not all data sets will have the same amount of Cycles and/or Tests within each Cycle so this template would need to have some flexibility to accommodate these changes, ie, no hard coded lines to look for specific values like Cycle 10 Test 20 because I may only have data for 5 Cycles and 10 Tests in each Cycle.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyh1o.jpg)

I have seen a few videos and threads on splitting a master sheet into multiple tabs.
Unfortunately for me they all are based on one column, while I have two columns required to filter my data.
I followed along with a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTySwuhpHG0) and was able to filter by the first column but I am not a proficient enough *coder* to repeat the process to subdivide each of those sheets by an additional column.

If anybody would be willing to help me through the process of adding a second filter that would be much appreciated!

Here are the first and last few rows of some sample data:

| CYCLE | TEST | TIME | RPM | PRESSURE | TEMP | TORQUE | MC | TRAVEL | Mu | INV TORQUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1615.574 | 297.804 | 84.185 | -239.611 | 0.181 | 0.219 | 18.781 | 239.611 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.01 | 1622.542 | 366.04 | 85.066 | -334.298 | 0.186 | 0.248 | 18.791 | 334.298 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.021 | 1616.027 | 414.561 | 84.237 | -360.269 | 0.192 | 0.236 | 18.802 | 360.269 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.032 | 1615.234 | 449.322 | 84.6 | -417.892 | 0.204 | 0.253 | 18.813 | 417.892 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.043 | 1615.687 | 520.937 | 84.6 | -497.428 | 0.215 | 0.259 | 18.824 | 497.428 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.053 | 1615.631 | 551.997 | 85.326 | -520.694 | 0.232 | 0.256 | 18.834 | 520.694 |
| 7 | 20 | 1.876 | 942.856 | 789.051 | 960.281 | -1047.147 | 0.421 | 0.361 | 17.879 | 1047.147 |
| 7 | 20 | 1.898 | 934.076 | 789.051 | 963.962 | -1048.771 | 0.421 | 0.361 | 17.901 | 1048.771 |
| 7 | 20 | 1.921 | 924.559 | 786.879 | 962.925 | -1129.93 | 0.42 | 0.39 | 17.924 | 1129.93 |
| 7 | 20 | 1.943 | 914.589 | 786.396 | 962.199 | -1075.283 | 0.421 | 0.372 | 17.946 | 1075.283 |
| 7 | 20 | 1.966 | 905.978 | 789.212 | 964.532 | -1018.201 | 0.42 | 0.351 | 17.969 | 1018.201 |
| 7 | 20 | 1.988 | 896.631 | 782.292 | 965.051 | -1124.79 | 0.421 | 0.391 | 17.991 | 1124.79 |

Comment: Would Cycle and Test be sequential in columns A and B or could they be mixed up so that you have to look through every row to see if it matches the current Cycle and Test?

Comment: The machine outputs a .tsv file containing all the data at the end of each run.  This is always formatted the same way, same columns, same order, the only thing it doesnt include is the row of headers which I add.  I would like to copy and paste that data into my sheets template (which would have the row 1 headers!), and have it split all the individual tests into new tabs (each tab should also keep the headers!).

Comment: At some point in time I would like it to also have the capability of graphing the data automatically but I have yet to finalize how I want that to look.  I'll cross that bridge when I come to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function splitData() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
    var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var cycle = data[1][0];  // Skip the first line header
    var test = data[1][1];
    var results = [data[1]];  // Put the first row in result
    var i = 0;
    function newTab(ss,cycle,test,results) {
      try {
        var name = "C_"+cycle+"_T_"+test;
        var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
        if( sh ) throw "Error sheet ["+name+"] already exists"
        sh = ss.insertSheet(name);
        sh.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
      }
      finally {
        return;
      }
    }
    for( i=2; i<data.length; i++ ) {  // Now we can start with row 2
      if( data[i][0] === cycle ) {
        if( data[i][1] === test ) {
          results.push(data[i]);
        }
        else {  // New test
          newTab(ss,cycle,test,results);
          test = data[i][1];
          results = [data[i]];
        }
      }
      else {  // New cycle
        newTab(ss,cycle,test,results);
        cycle = data[i][0];
        test = data[i][1];
        results = [data[i]];
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err)
  }
}
```

You could also import your TSV file with this:

```
function importTSV() {
  try {
    // Its best to get by Id otherwise if you have a lot of files getFilesByName can take a while
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1EV_uSnOcCUU-k9NinSnI7-aaQ_7xEae4");
    var data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    data = data.split("\n");
    var results = [["CYCLE","TEST","TIME","RPM"]]; // I only have 4 values per row in my test data 
    for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      results.push(data[i].split("\t"));
    }
    Logger.log(results)
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is so great!  One tweak I added was to delete out any pre-existing tabs before splitting up my data in case I accidentally saved over my template in the future with a full data set.  Deleting 100s of tabs one at a time sounded like a nightmare...    For the import TSV function it looks like its trying to grab a specific file name straight from Google drive?  Is there a way it can bring up a file browser to allow me to locate files?  I save each raw dataset to a specific folder but they all have unique names.

Comment: Take a look at Google file picker [link](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs).  There is a complete example on that page

Comment: I'm having issues with the script timing out on longer data sets now.  I see a lot of workarounds for running a few minutes at a time but the problem is you're limited to a certain amount of runtime/day so I might have troubling running multiple datasets over an entire day of testing.  Is there a way to sort more of this "locally"?

Comment: I tried to create a sheet with 100,000 rows and then read it back in and I got tired of watching the spinning wheel.  There is a way to batch process data but I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: Dumb me. The importTSV routine is not needed.  You could just import TSV from the Spreadsheet File menu.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still only able to run about half of a full data set before it times out, I've been reading about batching but its way over my head...  I might have to switch to Excel so it runs locally but I should be able to use this as a process template.

Comment: Just a thought.  I created a sheet with 100,000 rows.  getValues() for the entire sheet takes about 10 seconds.  Once in memory a loop through the whole thing takes a fraction of a second.  What you could do is look at an individual test.  Let 's say a sidebar says which cycle which test do you want.  Pull out that data, put it in a new sheet and you can look at it.